# Jammit appending filenames?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jammit

I'm using Jammit in my Rails application and am getting an error like this on my server:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/javascripts/landing/carousel_background.js/javascripts/landing/front.js"

The javascript files live in public/javascripts/landing, and my assets.yml looks like this:

```
embed_assets: off
gzip_assets: off
compress_assets: off

javascripts: 
  ....
  front:
    - public/javascripts/landing/carousel_background.js
    - public/javascripts/landing/front.js
  ...
```

My stylesheets get read fine but none of my js files. It looks like the js filenames are being concatenated and read as a single file instead of two separate files. Any idea what might be going on?

Edit:
Here's what the head of my layout looks like:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />


<%= render 'shared/title' %>

<%= render 'shared/import_styles' %>
<%= yield :stylesheets %> 
<%= render 'shared/import_ie_styles' %>

<%= include_stylesheets :landing, :media => :all %>

<%= render 'shared/import_scripts' %>
<%= include_javascripts :landing %>

<%= yield :head %>

<%= render 'shared/google_analytics' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>

<%= favicon_link_tag %>
</head>
```

and my view has these content_for tags:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= include_javascripts :front %>
<% end %>

<% content_for :stylesheets do %>
  <%= include_stylesheets :front, :media => :all %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that Jammits finished files are not in the same place as normal assets. You can't call the normal JavaScript methods such as `javascript_include_tag`, if you call `include_javascripts(:front)` it should work fine.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks. However, I'm not using any javascript_include_tag. I updated my question to show my <head> and content_for tags in my layout and view.

Comment: Is this in development or production? Is the URL you show thats 404 the exact one, and what version of Jammit. What you have looks fine and is the same as what I use without a problem.

Comment: It's in development and the server is running on port 3000 of localhost, so the URL is right. It's Jammit version 0.6.5, which is the latest version.

Comment: Nevermind, after a 'bundle show', turns out I was using Jammit 0.6.0 and Rails 3.1, which don't mix well. After changing my Gemfile to include Jammit 0.6.5. everything worked.